# jquery autofill on select: “button event”

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sorry for the previous post, I have an autocomplete dropdown box, after the user selects an item out of the list I need the code to sent to the server side. I thought I could use the select: function to do this but nothing.. Any help would be appreciated

CODE:

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
<style type="text/css"> .ui-autocomplete { position: absolute; cursor: default; font-size:12px; font-family:Arial;} </style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".tb").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "EmployeeList.asmx/FetchEmailList",
                    data: "{ 'mail': '" + request.term + "' }",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                value: item.Email
                            }
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus);
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 3,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $(".ImageButton1").click();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "source" property of the autocomplete constructor defines what the options for the select object are, not what happens when it changes. You're going to want something like:

```
$(".tb").autocomplete({
  //This can be the result of a GET also
  //Or any function that returns a legitimate type for source
  source: ["your", "options", "here"] 
})
```

However to post data when a user selects something, you want to use the change event like so:

```
$(".tb").change( function () {
  $.ajax({
                    url: "EmployeeList.asmx/FetchEmailList",
                    data: "{ 'mail': '" + request.term + "' }",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                value: item.Email
                            }
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus);
                    }
                });
}
```

This script will attach an event handler to the "change" event (whenever a user uses your select widget) that sends the result (Assuming you have bound the data to request.term correctly) to the server side endpoint: "EmployeeList.asmx/FetchEmailList"

Also, consider using

```
$(".tb").val()
```

If you have trouble binding the term data to request.term.

EDIT:

It seems OP wanted to fire the click event or send the ajax request in a different event.

```
$(".tb").change( function () {
  //Manually fire a click event like this
  $(".ImageButton1").trigger("click");
})
```

Of course, you will need some code attached to the image button's click event for this to do anything.

```
$("ImageButton1").click( function () {
  //Some code here, for instance your ajax request
  //This will fire on the change event of your select object also if you include the code in this example
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this stuff is new to me. I just want to rais event ImageButton1.click after the user selects from the dropdown. Should be easy. This code works fine, but the user should not have to manually click on a button.

Comment: They do not have to manually click a button, as the event fires whenever your select object changes.

Comment: I added the code necessary to force .click() on your button whenever the select element changes.

Answer (score 0):

It was as simple as I thought, syntax: change

```
select: function (event, ui) {
            $(".ImageButton1").click();
```

to

```
select: function () { $('#ImageButton1').click(); }
```

This works fine and is simple (Thanks again)